# Unresolved package name even though everything is fine

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android, android-manifest

I'm doing an android project in Xamarin.Android. I have a problem with android manifest. I want to register receiver for my Notification ContextIntent by using PendingIntent.GetBroadcast. In order to trigger OnReceive that broadcast I have to register receiver explicitly in my android.manifest. But ... It can't see my class and package name.

I tried deleting .idle folder and building once again. Also I invalidated caches and restarted JetBrains Rider. And still it doesn't work. 
I didn't touch package name.
"PPCAndroid.PPCAndroid.JobServices.StartWorkReceiver"
JobServices is a folder, which I keep StartWorkReceiver class in.
Namespace of that class is: "PPCAndroid.JobServices"
I also tried in in my receiver's name values like this:

```
PPCAndroid.PPCAndroid.JobServices.StartWorkReceiver
PPCAndroid.JobServices.StartWorkReceiver
.JobServices.StartWorkReceiver
.StartWorkReceiver
```

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:versionCode="1" 
      android:versionName="1.0" 
      package="PPCAndroid.PPCAndroid">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"     
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme">
<receiver
       android:name="PPCAndroid.PPCAndroid.JobServices.StartWorkReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I want my android manifest to see StartWorkReceiver class. 
Now I'm getting an error like this: `Unresolved package 'PPCAndroid'`.

Comment: are you sure that you should do this? AFAIK in Xamarin we are doing this via Attributes and `<receiver/>` in manifest is generated

Comment: You mean by using braces like that: [Receiver]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xamarin, you can also use [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.attribute?view=netframework-4.8). Have a look at the `BroadcastReceiverAttribute` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.broadcastreceiverattribute?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)).

> Generates a /manifest/application/receiver element within AndroidManifest.xml.